# Soap address as requested url on Wildfly webservice

Tags: web-services, soap, wsdl, wildfly, wildfly-9

I have a wsdl webservice running on a Wildfly 9 server.

My application is on a Virtual Server that answers only on a specific DNS.

When i get the wsdl ( mydns.com/MyWebservice?wsdl ) it come with the soap:address like that:

`<soap:address location="http://10.125.31.9:8080/MyWebservice"/>`

I have changed the subsystem configuration to not override the soap:Address with:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:webservices:2.0">
            <modify-wsdl-address>false</modify-wsdl-address>
            <endpoint-config name="Standard-Endpoint-Config"/>
            <endpoint-config name="Recording-Endpoint-Config">
                <pre-handler-chain name="recording-handlers" protocol-bindings="##SOAP11_HTTP ##SOAP11_HTTP_MTOM ##SOAP12_HTTP ##SOAP12_HTTP_MTOM">
                    <handler name="RecordingHandler" class="org.jboss.ws.common.invocation.RecordingServerHandler"/>
                </pre-handler-chain>
            </endpoint-config>
            <client-config name="Standard-Client-Config"/>
        </subsystem>
```

And now i get the soap:address `http://jbossws.undefined.host:8080/AutenticacaoAcessoWs`

I need wildfly to not change anything on my soap:address. If the user requests http://mydns.com/MyWebservice?wsdl i need the soap:address to be http://mydns.com/MyWebservice

How can i do that?

Comment: Is the "Virtual Server" able to perform a reverse lookup on `10.125.31.9` and get `mydns.com`?

Comment: When i say Virtual Server i'm referring to the Wildfly virtual server configuration....

Comment: Nevertheless, can the server that hosts your WildFly instance perform that reverse lookup successfully?

Comment: I don't think so, because there are many DNS's on the same IP.